# Remove multiple checked items from list view using iterator

Tags: android, listview, iterator

I have a ListView which uses `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`.
Once the user has made their selections, I need to remove the selected items from the list.

I have used `getCheckedItemPositions()` to return the SparseBooleanArray of checked items.

All the documentation and related questions I've read indicate that to remove items from a list efficiently, you should use an **Iterator**, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have achieved the same operation by looping though the items in the ListView by index and using a temporary clone of the items list to look up which items should be removed (see code below). But supposedly looping through indexes like this to remove items from a List = *Bad Coding Monkey*. I'm told I should do it with an Iterator instead. But how?

```
protected void removeItems() {
    SparseBooleanArray itemsSelectionState = mItemsListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
    ArrayList<String> itemsClone = (ArrayList<String>) mItems.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < mItemsListView.getCount(); i++) {
        if (itemsSelectionState.get(i) == true) {
            mItems.remove(itemsClone.get(i));
        }
    }
    mItemsListView.clearChoices();
    mItemsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the position anyway to lookup the boolean value in the Sparse array.  there's not much point in using an iterator if you have to maintain an index value to determine if you should remove that item.

Yes, I think your approach is valid. The iterator does have a remove() method, but you would still need have an index handy. If the id's are stable (with ArrayList based adapters, the id usually equals the position) then it might be more efficient to use getItemIds () and iterate through that list, using the id's as positions.

```
// could also store ids[] and pre-allocate mItemsClone to ids.length
for (long id : ..getItemIds() ){ 
  itemsClone.put( mItems.get( (int) id) );
}
```

and that might be a bit more efficient since it's only one pass

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just checking... are you saying my approach is valid for this situation, so don't sweat it?